# OpenCV Pixel Intensities

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm just looking for an explanation behind OpenCV's coordinate system and its pixel intensity system. I am using a for loop to find the most intense pixel on the screen (I am aware that I could use minMaxLoc to find it, however, my code will be changed to find the leftmost pixel as well so this for loop is needed).

```
for (int i = 0; i < imgHight; i++) //Going through the height or Y axis.
{                                   // The height and width are equal the image is a square
    for (int j = 0; j < imgWidth; j++) //  Going through the width or X axis. 
    {
        newInten = grayImg.at<uchar>(j, i); // This uses the X and Y to find a new point
        HeadInten = grayImg.at<uchar>(Head); // This uses the stored XY as a comparassion
        newIntenVal = newInten.val[0]; // This finds the intensity of the pixel at this point
        if (newIntenVal > LowerBounds) //Compaired to lower bounds (80% of max pixel intensity)
        {

            if (newIntenVal > HeadIntenVal) // If the new intensity is higher than old then change head to new point and run again.
            {
                //cout << newInten << " " << HeadInten << " " << i << " " << j << endl;
                Head = { j, i};
                HeadIntenVal = HeadInten.val[0]; // Finds the intensity of pixel at stored head.

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then draw a circle around Head to show its position on the picture. The issue is, that currently, this draws in a random place, but when Head = {i, j} (X and Y are reversed) then this draws in the expected place. Is there any suggestion as to why this might happen?
Incorrect circle : [image: https://gyazo.com/bc7808c7a9de724a33a587f1524d10f5]
Correct circle: [image: https://gyazo.com/560a460822a45d24c2dcbae31cd5c8d5]

The problem feeds into trying to find the intensity of that pixel again using the point values of Head, this then gives me a different result and cannot be used for comparison later on.

Many Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Full code - Sorry its a bit of a mess

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    double IBKG, IMAX, TC, LowerBounds; // IBKG is Image Background Level 
    Intensity, IMAX is Maximum Image Intensity, TC is comet theshold
    Point IBKG_LOC, IMAX_LOC; // These are the respective locations on the 
    image, head is to find the head of the comet

    Mat img = imread("Test1.png");
    Mat grayImg;
    int imgHight = img.rows;
    int imgWidth = img.cols;
    cout << imgHight << " " << imgWidth << endl;

    cvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    minMaxLoc(grayImg, &IBKG, &IMAX, &IBKG_LOC, &IMAX_LOC);
    cout << IMAX_LOC << endl;
    TC = (IBKG + IMAX) / 2;
    LowerBounds = IMAX * 0.8;
    cout << LowerBounds << endl;
    uint8_t newInten;
    int maxX = 0, maxY = 0;
    uint8_t grayMax = grayImg.at<uint8_t>(maxY, maxX);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgHight; i++) //Going through the height or Y axis.
    {                                   // The height and width are equal the image is a square
        for (int j = 0; j < imgWidth; j++) //  Going through the width or X axis. 
        {
            uint8_t newInten = grayImg.at<uchar>(i,j); // This uses the X and Y to find a new point

            if (newInten > LowerBounds) //Compaired to lower bounds (80% of max pixel intensity)
            {

                if (newInten > grayMax) // If the new intensity is higher than old then change head to new point and run again.
                {
                grayMax = newInten;
                maxX = j;
                maxY = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Point LeftSide;
    bool leftSideFlag = false;
    for (int i = maxX; i > 0; i--)
    {
        newInten = grayImg.at<uchar>(maxY, i);

        if (!leftSideFlag)
        {
            if (newInten < TC)
            {
                LeftSide = { maxY, i};
                leftSideFlag = true;
                //i = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    int CircleRadius = maxX - LeftSide.x;

    circle(img, Point(maxY, maxX), 10, Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    cout << IBKG <<" " << IMAX << " " << IBKG_LOC << " "  << IMAX_LOC << " " << TC << endl;
    namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    namedWindow("Gray Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("Image", img);
    imshow("Gray Image", grayImg);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: The screenshot links don't appear to show what you're describing - can you try to upload them to Stack Overflow using the image upload button?

Comment: I cant upload images due to not having enough rep :/ Keeps saying I need 10 rep to post the image directly. I checked the link and it shows it properly if you zoom in, maybe if I change the circle colour it will be easier to see.

Comment: The circle has been changed to white and the picture should be more zoomed on the area! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is just plain inefficient - remember HeadInten` alongside `Head`, instead of recalculating it every time.

Comment: Im completely new to the library, so it was just a hash out to be fair but I can change that now.

Comment: `grayImg.at<uchar>(j, i)` should be `grayImg.at<uchar>(i, j)` OpenCV uses matrix notation for the cv::Mat functions, this means (row, col) or in cartesian coordinates language (y,x)... I suppose Head is cv::Point which actually uses cartesian coordinates so (x,y) .... I know it is confusing, but... it is like that. And `.at` already gives you an uchar... there is no need to do `.val[0]`

Answer (score 1):

The Mat.at function needs parameters row , column order.
So first Y and then X

```
int imgHight = grayImg.rows;
int imgWidth = grayImg.cols;
int maxX = 0, maxY = 0;
uint8_t grayMax = grayImg.at<uint8_t>(maxY,maxX);

for (int i = 0; i < imgHight; i++) //Going through the height or Y axis.
{                                   // The height and width are equal the image is a square
    for (int j = 0; j < imgWidth; j++) //  Going through the width or X axis. 
    {
        uint8_t newInten = grayImg.at<uchar>(i, j); // This uses the X and Y to find a new point
        if (newInten > grayMax)
        {
            grayMax = newInten;
            maxX = j;
            maxY = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Also changed the code a bit to make it faster.
Not the fastest possible option though.

Comment: Just changed this as suggested, the outcome is the same, I'm going to upload the whole code as well! Thank you for helping though I had no idea it was a YX system

Answer (score 1):

After adding the suggested fixes I swapped the X and Y round the way I would expect them normally for drawing the circle, I also needed to remember to compare maxX to Leftside.y. The outcome is now as expected. Thank you all!